# About with(any(Class.class))) with JMock

Tags: java, testing, jmock

With JMock:

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    // Other oneOf() will() statements ...

    oneOf(shopAccount).enter(100, with(any(String.class)));
    will(returnValue(true));

   // Other oneOf() will() statements ...
}});
```

The following exception will be raised during execution:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not all parameters were given explicit matchers: either all parameters must be specified by matchers or all must be specified by values, you cannot mix matchers and values.

Why i cannot do this way? using `with(any(Klass.class))` ?

Answer (score 23):

if you use a `with` clause for any parameter, you must use them for all the parameters, try

> oneOf(shopAccount).enter(**with(equalTo(100))**, with(any(String.class)));

Comment: Isn't it `with(equal(100))`, not `equalTo`?

Comment: is you mean 'equals()', then that's a method on Object that returns a boolean. 'equalto()' is a static matcher method that returns a matcher.

Comment: @Lukas `org.jmock.Expectations.equal(T)` and `org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo(T)` are defined equivalently (at least in versions jmock-2.5.1 and junit-4.8.2), so either would work.