# JMock expectation IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jmock

I am trying to use the `allowing` method to fix the return value of a method on one of my mocked objects. I have the following method on a mocked object `jdbc` which I want to allow for:

```
List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

I am using `with(any(RowMapper.class))` because I don't really care which `RowMapper` is used - I just want to make sure that when it calls `query` with that SQL it returns a `List` with `"bob"`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.jmock.auto.Mock;
import org.jmock.integration.junit4.JUnitRuleMockery;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcOperations;

public class GetCustomersPhaseTest
{
    @Rule
    public final JUnitRuleMockery mockery = new JUnitRuleMockery();

    @Mock
    private SimpleJdbcOperations jdbc;

    @Mock
    private EventPublisher events;

    @Mock
    private Context context;

    private GetCustomersPhase phase;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        phase = new GetCustomersPhase(jdbc, events);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCustomers()
    {
        mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
            {
                allowing(jdbc).query(with(equal("SELECT Name FROM Customers")), with(any(RowMapper.class)));
                will(returnValue(Arrays.asList("Bob")));
            }
        });

        phase.execute(context);
    }
}
```

However this gives me,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not all parameters were given explicit matchers: either all parameters must be specified by matchers or all must be specified by values, you cannot mix matchers and values
    at org.jmock.internal.InvocationExpectationBuilder.checkParameterMatcherCount(InvocationExpectationBuilder.java:98)
    at org.jmock.internal.InvocationExpectationBuilder.createExpectationFrom(InvocationExpectationBuilder.java:91)
    at org.jmock.internal.InvocationToExpectationTranslator.invoke(InvocationToExpectationTranslator.java:19)
    at org.jmock.internal.FakeObjectMethods.invoke(FakeObjectMethods.java:38)
    at org.jmock.lib.JavaReflectionImposteriser$1.invoke(JavaReflectionImposteriser.java:33)
    at $Proxy10.query(Unknown Source)
    at com.thecat.test.GetCustomersPhaseTest$1.<init>(GetCustomersPhaseTest.java:45)
    at com.thecat.test.GetCustomersPhaseTest.testGetCustomers(GetCustomersPhaseTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.jmock.integration.junit4.JUnitRuleMockery$1.evaluate(JUnitRuleMockery.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761529/about-withanyclass-class-with-jmock) and tried to solve the issue but I still cant get it work.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Are you sure you've identified the correct expectation that's failing?

Comment: Ive provided some more code, I was using a Hamcrest `equalTo` method. I am now using the `equal` method from `Expectations`.

Comment: figured it out, silly varargs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleJdbcOperations#query` takes an `Object...` as the final parameter. The error occurs because this is not accounted for by a `with` method, I think its because this compiles down to passing an empty array to this method which is not accounted for.

It works if you use,

```
allowing(jdbc).query(with(equal("SELECT Name FROM Customers")), with(any(RowMapper.class)), with(equal(new Object[0])));
will(returnValue(Arrays.asList("Bob")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick first check, can you make sure you're importing the right with(), equalTo() and any() methods? sometimes there are similar methods from other packages.

Comment: Ive provided some more code, I was using a Hamcrest `equalTo` method. I am now using the `equal` method from `Expectations`.